# Как в оперативной памяти представлены числа с плавающей запятой?

Tags: c++, c

Как в оперативной памяти представить вещественное число, если с обычными числами вроде все более менее понятно (под переменную выделяется память и туда в двоичной форме записывается число), то с вещественными числами не все так просто понять)) Как вообще компьютер понимает дробное это число или нет, как он понимает как его нужно складывать, делить и умножать. И еще вопрос из этой же темы почему разрядность процессора влияет на точность вещественного число. Ведь если мы возьмем 32 битный процессор и возьмем тип данных long, который занимает 64 бита, то процессор не сможет за раз обработать число с этим типом данных и он разобьет эту операцию на несколько инструкций, так вот почему так нельзя сделать с вещественным числом и получить высокую точность? Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: [Ассемблер IA-32. Вещественная арифметика - МГТУ им. Баумана (pdf)](http://e-learning.bmstu.ru/moodle/file.php/1/common_files/library/SPO/FPU/bmstu_iu6_Sysprogr_Floating_point.pdf)

Comment: *"почему так нельзя сделать с вещественным числом"* Почему нельзя? Можно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну а зачем тогда пишут что в научных целях для более высокой точности используют процессор с большей разрядностью ?

Comment: Разрядность процессора в современных реалиях обычно относится к размеру указателя, видимого из пользовательского кода. т.е. 32 битный процессор вполне может обрабатывать и 64 битный long и 64 битный double безо всяких затруднений и разбиений на мелкие инструкции. Про использование процессора с большей разрядностью для большей точности - это уже архаизм.

Comment: Кроме того, компьютер ничего не понимает, а программа - это как раз перечень инструкций для процессора, что откуда брать, что делать и куда класть результат.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Как вообще компьютер понимает дробное это число или нет, как он понимает как его нужно складывать, делить и умножать.

Процессор никак не может знать тип данных, хранящийся по тому или иному адресу памяти. Для него это просто последовательность байт. Смысл, структура и размер определяются исключительно текущей командой процессора и её флагами. То есть вы можете, например, сначала записать по некоему адресу целое восьмибайтное число (`mov [адрес], 1234567812345678h`), а затем взять первые четыре байта из восьми и поместить их в стек математического сопроцессора, будто это дробное число одинарной точности (`fld dword [адрес]`). Разумеется, значение в стеке будет уже другим, так как хоть байты одни и те же, но изменилась их интерпретация.

То есть единственное место процессора, знающее как работать с вещественными числами — это соответствующая часть арифметико-логического устройства. Для остальной части процессора это просто некая последовательность байт.

Однако из этого правила есть исключения. Например Эльбрусы работают с меченой (тегированной) памятью, где тип данных в каждой ячейке задаётся при записи в неё и хранится в области атрибутов. И тут процессор действительно знает, какой тип данных где лежит.

> Как в оперативной памяти представить вещественное число, если с обычными числами вроде все более менее понятно (под переменную выделяется память и туда в двоичной форме записывается число), то с вещественными числами не все так просто понять

Из первого пункта ответа становится понятным, что для переменных типа чисел с плавающей запятой также выделяется память, и туда также в двоичном виде записывается число (четыре байта для чисел одинарной точности и восемь для двойной).

> И еще вопрос из этой же темы почему разрядность процессора влияет на точность вещественного числа? Ведь если мы возьмем 32 битный процессор и возьмем тип данных long, который занимает 64 бита, то процессор не сможет за раз обработать число с этим типом данных и он разобьет эту операцию на несколько инструкций, так вот почему так нельзя сделать с вещественным числом и получить высокую точность?

Какой бы из двух способов обработки вещественных мы не выбрали, ни один из них не зависит от разрядности процессора:

- Intel 8087 (который FPU) и его эмуляция в более современных процессорах работают в своём, 80-разрядном формате, который фиксирован и никак не может совпадать с разрядностью процессора, ибо не степень двойки.
- Скалярные операции (SIMD — например SSE или AVX) также оперируют буферами фиксированного размера в 128 бит, превышающего разрядность процессора. Соответственно, и разбиение этого буфера на отдельные числа также ни на что не завязано, ибо за это также отвечает отдельный вычислительный блок.

Таким образом, разрядность процессора влияет здесь только опосредованно и только на количество тактов, требуемое для загрузки вещественных чисел.

А вот на что разрядность действительно влияет, так это на размер обычных регистров, которые как раз и используются в целочисленной арифметике.

> Как вообще хранится это число в памяти? Имеется в виду как отделяется целая часть от дробной, если в жизни мы можем отделить по знаку запятой, то как компьютер хранит это в памяти? Отдельно целую отдельно дробную часть?

Если говорить простыми словами, вещественное число хранится как совокупность трёх компонент:

1. Знак (хранится отдельно для нужд математического анализа, где существуют положительный и отрицательный ноль).
2. Число вида `1,xxxxxxx...`. Причём способ хранения этого числа достаточно интересный, в виде суммы вида:

   [image: 1,0 + a_1\frac{1}{2} + a_2\frac{1}{4} + a_3\frac{1}{8} + ... + a_n\frac{1}{2^n}]

   где различные *a* — это нули и единицы, значение которых формирует *мантиссу*.
3. Количество двоичных разрядов, на которое надо сдвинуть запятую для получения нужного числа. В десятичном виде это будет выглядеть как умножение на целую степень двойки. Это называется *порядок*.

Но это верно только для стандарта IEEE 754. Существуют архитектуры и с другим представлением вещественных чисел, однако они не так распространены.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, но для меня все равно осталось непонятным как вообще хранится это число в памяти ? Имеется в виду как отделяется целая часть от дробной если в жизни мы можем отделить по знаку запятой то как компьютер хранит это в памяти ? Отдельно целую отдельно дробную часть ?

Comment: @НикитаАнтонов, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @НикитаАнтонов, советую ознакомиться с [этим обзором](http://www.softelectro.ru/ieee754.html) (на русском) стандарта IEEE 754. Написано все очень простым языком, да и сам принцип хранения чисел тоже довольно прост. Нужно просто посидеть немного и вы обязательно всё поймете.